# Using tornado to serve large files

Tags: python, tornado

We have a need for to use Tornado for serving large files (multiple GBs) that require authentication to access. From what we can tell, doing this with a `get` and chunking the files via `Task` will potentially be slow or block. Is there a recommended method for serving large files that require authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/sgadmx8Hd_s) is the best solution. Note that is a combination of tornado and nginx.

Comment: @HarshalPatil the basic idea is to use nginx to download the file vs. tornado. In short, let's assume you have your protected files in a protected (internal) folder accessible via nginx. Then you will need 2 tornado handlers: (1) one that is called when the user clicks on the download link, does the user validation, sets a protected cookie, and redirects to the second handler, and (2) a simple handler that redirects with "X-Accel-Redirect" so nginx knows that needs to send the file. Hope this helps.